# I am getting a bunch of extra chars when i try to reverse a cstring in c++

Tags: c++, reverse, cstring

The string entered by the user appears to be reversed but it is also followed by a bunch of garbage chars. Here is my reverse function:

```
void reverse(char str[])
{
    char reversed[MAX_CHAR];

    for(int i = 0; i < strlen(str); i++)
    {
        reversed[i] = str[strlen(str) - i - 1];
    }

    cout << reversed << endl;
}
```

Comment: By the way, C++ has `std::reverse`.

Comment: Don't try this with a multi-byte string.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to end your string with the `NULL` character `'\0'`, ASCII value `0`.

Try this:

```
void reverse(char str[]) {
  char reversed[MAX_CHAR];
  int len = strlen(str);

  for(int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    reversed[i] = str[len - i - 1];
  }

  reversed[len] = '\0'; // Add this

  cout << reversed << endl;
}
```

This is how `C` and `C++` know where the end of the string is.

Read more about Null-terminated character sequences:

- http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/ntcs/
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null-terminated_string

Comment: That is exactly what i needed thanks! The funny thing is i thought i tried that but i typed '\n' instead of '\0' because i thought you were supposed to end the string with a newline char instead of the NULL char. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @chillpenguin - No problem. Yeah this can be confusing when you compare it to reading input with something like [`getline()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/getline/) where it reads up until the new line.

Answer (score 0):

you can solve this in 2 ways either by
a)  initializing reversed array with null chars

```
char reversed[MAX_CHAR] = {0};
```

b) adding null character by end of the reversed string.

```
reversed[strlen(str)] = '\0';
```